# no module error on python when I connect EC2 with ssh

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am a junior(more like kindergarten to be specific) web developer and I get some project which already exists. it is deployed on EC2 and I had to deal with some python files.
I wanted to execute python files, So I connect project with ssh via key files.
and I tried to execute python files but I couldn't and get a message like this.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Well, I thought I could run a file because modules are already downloaded on EC2server??
how can I solve this and run python file on ssh?

ps. when I make a new python file and run print("pypy") It runs OK

thx for reading, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your script apparently requires ```bs4``` which isn't installed.  How was the project deployed?  You need to make sure that you use the same deployment scheme.

Comment: "bs4" is the module for BeautifulSoup.  It's not built-in; you have to install it.  Have you tried `pip install bs4`?